# points of R plot (saved to pdf) are not showing up with pdflatex

Tags: graphics, pdftex, pdf, r

I am generating a pdf plot with R:

```
library("ROCR")
p <- c(0.226809355461365, 0.230331183191861, 0.245193329547248, 0.230982114615013, 
0.231497802927267, 0.2296662312173, 0.224856867748048, 0.230695540365456, 
0.236123643694864, 0.231331519186633, 0.24379985029512, 0.226912065850285, 
0.23417412288571, 0.235899589363286, 0.228283031513041, 0.23916147294911, 
0.232824226161469, 0.230780562962366, 0.234744032499568, 0.22916648058246
)

o <- structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("pos", "neg"), class = "factor")
pred <- prediction(p, o, label.ordering = c("neg", "pos"))
perf <- performance(pred, measure = "tpr", x.measure = "fpr")

pdf(file = "test.pdf", width = 3, height = 3)
plot(perf, avg="threshold", print.cutoffs.at=0.23, text.adj=c(0.5,1.5))
dev.off()
```

[image: The example plot]

This plot has a point. When I try to display it with pdflatex, the point doesn't show (but the rest if fine). Also, the pdf figure does have the point (seen when opened with a pdf viewer directly).

```
\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.6\linewidth]{../test}
\caption{Do you see any points?}
\end{figure}
```

I am not sure what information about my tex config I should give, so please ask if I forget anything important. I use pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.15 (MiKTeX 2.9) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2015.5.29).

I am pretty sure I saw some resources one day about this very problem but I wasn't able to find it back with google.

Comment: Do you mean the circle labelled "0.23"?

Comment: I do. I call it a point because it's a point object in R graphics while the line (although mathematically composed of points) is a line object.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I encountered similar issue and then realised it was the preview of my editor (texstudio) which was responsible as when I opened the pdf file points were showing up.

Maybe it can help.

Answer (score 0):

I usually make the plots within R and export it to SVG. Then I use son image editor such as Inkscape to create a PDF version. This PDF version looks nice in the final latex document. I have done this several time with optimal results.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question at hand, and is better-suited as a comment.